# Not able to access data sent through ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cross-domain

So I am sending a variable through ajax in my php file. Here's my code

```
getVoteCount: function(){
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        instance.candidates(i).then(function(candidate) {
            var vName = candidate[1];
            var vCount = candidate[2];
            var x = (vCount+" ");
            var y = vName;
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/Election/EVoting/src/MegaProjectWebsite/generateResult.php',
                    data: {'vote_to_send' : x},
                }).done(function(result) {
                    result1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
                    **console.log("Result is "+result1);**
                })
            })
```

Now my php code is as follows:

```
<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    echo "hello";
        $x =  $_POST['vote_to_send'];
        echo $x;
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'letsvote');
    $sql = "insert into result (vote_count) values (".$_POST['vote_to_send']. ")";
    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {echo "done";}
    else{
      echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

The problem is, I cannot access the variable `($_POST['vote_to_send'])`. It gives the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: vote_to_send in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Election\EVoting\src\MegaProjectWebsite\generateResult.php
>   on line 4

Because of this, the insert operation also fails.
However the result is visible in the console in `result1` (given in bold above) in the `.done()` function. I am unable to understand why this is happening!

Comment: You're doing AJAX in a loop; are you seeing results and the notice for each iteration?

Comment: Yes, the result is visible in loop. But when i run the php file separately, I get the error stated above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: I tried using if( isset($_POST['vote_to_send'])), it always goes in the else part.

Comment: Run separately? Meaning directly opening the page? Of course you get that notice since there is no post request then.

Comment: You need to check the request body and see what is being sent to the server

Comment: Yes, because I'm trying to insert that value in my database, so when I tried doing that I got the error, so I started putting break points and noticed that the value is not getting accessed, and hence not getting entered into the db via php file

Comment: A script made for an AJAX action is not meant to be accessed directly. If you had trouble inserting into the database, then you should have posted that.

Comment: Alon, how do I do that? Checking the request body?

Comment: But at least I should get the value I'm sending through ajax in that variable when I echo it

Comment: Well, you said you are seeing it now in the console. Meaning something else was the problem if you had some other code before the echo. I suggest you edit the question with the code that was trying to insert because, at the moment, there is no problem with your script (outside of you trying to access that page directly, which makes no sense).

Comment: I have added my database insertion code, you may have a look now

Comment: And what is the issue with it? What do you get in the response, what does the console show? You're also wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Output :   Result is <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: vote_to_send in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Election\EVoting\src\MegaProjectWebsite\generateResult.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />

Comment: Does `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:(http://localhost/Election/EVoting/src/MegaProjectWebsite/generateResult.php')` help?

Comment: I just used Get instead of post and it worked. Thanks for your help though! I don't know how it worked, but it did :D

Comment: Did you change HTTP request to GET in both PHP and jQuery?

Comment: Yesss, it worked

Comment: It is better to use POST requests. GET request is bad for security

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to mention `dataType` in your AJAX call. PHP server-side does not get data type information, hence it is spitting out an error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/Election/EVoting/src/MegaProjectWebsite/generateResult.php',
                    data: {'vote_to_send' : x},
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function(result) {
                    result1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
                    **console.log("Result is "+result1);**
                })
```

`dataType` specifies what is the type of data is jQuery is expecting from server. If it is JSON, do `dataType:'json'` or something else accordingly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error. You wrote it yourself, it defines what "jQuery is expecting from server", not the other way around.

Comment: adding the data type doesn't make any difference! The error still persists. Thanks for the help, though!